# 415 status code in the deployed version of angular but on local no 415 error while sending request

Tags: angular, api, rest, .net-core, http-post

My angular application is receiving 415 status code upon sending a request in deployed version.

In local version, there is no 415 error and I see 200 status code for the same request.

Other points to note:

- For the same request, in local, the request header has the content-type "application/json"
- For the same request, in deployed angular application, the request header has the content-type as "text/plain". Not sure why this changed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you will find some solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669615/angular-http-post-request-content-type-from-text-plain-to-application-json

But I don't know why this is necessary.  I have an angular application deployed and I don't need to tell it to use that content  type "application/json" it just does so automatically.  I'm hoping for someone smarter than me to answer your question here.

Comment: For this particular request, nothing is being mentioned explicitly. In local, Content type is application/json but in deployed one it's text/plain

Comment: Where are you deploying this?  Is this in IIS?

Comment: Yes it's deployed in iis

Comment: I wonder if there are somethings you need to do here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

In particular, there is a section for IIS deployments.  At the end of the day, you can set your headers yourself with an http-interceptor, but I'm surprised that you would have to

Comment: I read somewhere that someone was using IIS Express and they were seeing this same issue, but when they switched to using normal IIS the problem went away.  This is starting to seem like an IIS configuration issue and not an angular one.  I believe that application/json is the default content-type in angular.  Can you confirm it is the POST request and not the OPTION request that is causing the problem?  Can you share your network tab in chrome dev tools?